# Callback when a block is deallocated

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa

I am calling into Cocoa from C, all through the Obj-C runtime.

I am able to create block objects with the info from here[1] and pass them as arguments to Cocoa methods which retain them as needed, and release them when they are no longer needed. The problem is that I need to release other resources associated with the block when the block reaches refcount 0 and is deallocated, so I need a way to set a callback for when that happens.

With normal objects, I would just subclass and override dealloc(). I hear blocks are objects too - is there a Block class that can be subclassed? Or is there any other way to hook up a function on release and/or dealloc of blocks?

Thanks.

[1] http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html

Comment: I'm curious-- what other resources would you need to release?

Comment: Why is the dispose_helper described in the document you reference not suitable for your needs?

Comment: @stevesliva luajit callback objects, created to wrap Lua functions as blocks.

Comment: @CRD because it's never called. I tried a stack block, a global block, set bit 25, 28, 29, but the function is not called and inside the callback the 'reserved' field (which should store the refcount) doesn't get incremented.

Comment: @cap - see the answer I added a couple of days ago. My test code called the function - the test was an Xcode OS X app.

Comment: @CRD can you please give me some details or share that code? Do you create a stack block or a global block? When is the block retained and when it is released and when it is disposed? Thanks.

Comment: @cap - see the answer, actual code added as an addendum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is how I solved it.

First I created a `block_literal` (defined to have a `block_descriptor` attached).

```
struct block_descriptor {
    unsigned long int reserved;         // NULL
    unsigned long int size;             // sizeof(struct block_literal)
    copy_helper_t     copy_helper;      // IFF (1<<25)
    dispose_helper_t  dispose_helper;   // IFF (1<<25)
};

struct block_literal {
    struct block_literal *isa;
    int flags;
    int reserved;
    void *invoke;
    struct block_descriptor *descriptor;
    struct block_descriptor d; // because they come in pairs
};
```

This is how you should set the fields:

```
block.isa        = _NSConcreteStackBlock //stack block because global blocks are not copied/disposed
block.flags      = 1<<25 //has copy & dispose helpers
block.reserved   = 0
block.invoke     = my_callback_function
block.descriptor = &block.d
block.d.reserved = 0
block.d.size     = sizeof(block_literal)
block.d.copy_helper    = my_copy_callback
block.d.dispose_helper = my_dispose_callback
```

I keep a refcount per each created block which starts at 1, and which is incremented in `my_copy_callback` and decremented in `my_dispose_callback`. When the refcount reaches 0 the resources associated with the block gets released.

Note: copy/dispose helpers will not be called on synchronous methods like NSString's `enumerateLinesUsingBlock` because these methods don't retain/release the block while using it because they assume that the block remains available for the duration of the call. OTOH, an async method like `dispatch_async()` does invoke the helpers. Calling `dispatch_async()` multiple times on the same block should show the refcount incremented twice and then decremented.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Obj-C Associated Objects API](http://kingscocoa.com/tutorials/associated-objects/) to associate an object instance with a block instance.  The associated object will (if it is not accessed anywhere else) be deallocated when the block is deallocated.

Use the `-dealloc` method of the associated object to execute any desired resource cleanup, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work for blocks in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment:

I'll assume you are using the Clang compiler to create your blocks in C, if you are creating the block description structs yourself the idea is the same but you can create the structs directly with the correct values.

If you wish to call a cleanup function when a block is disposed of then (in outline):

```
if (bObject->flags & BLOCK_HAS_COPY_DISPOSE)
{
   // block already has a dispose helper
   // save current dispose helper in a lookup table with key the bObject
   bObject->descriptor->dispose_helper = function which:
                                         a) uses the lookup table to call the original helper
                                         b) removes the entry from the lookup table
                                         c) calls your cleanup function
}
else
{
   // block does not have a dispose helper
   bObject->flags |= BLOCK_HAS_COPY_DISPOSE; // set is has helpers
   bObject->descriptor->copy_helper = dummy copy function
   bObject->descriptor->dispose_helper = dispose function which just calls your cleanup
}
```

You need a lookup table to store a map from block addresses to helper addresses, e.g. `NSMapTable`.

HTH

**Addendum**

As requested in comments my quick'n'dirty test code, it just follows the pseudo-code above. Run this and you should see the second and third blocks get disposed, the first is not as its a static literal and doesn't need disposing.

```
void DummyBlockCopy(void *src, void *dst)
{
}

void BlockDispose(void *src)
{
    printf("BlockDispose %p\n", src);
}

typedef void (*HelperFunction)(void *);

NSMapTable *disposeHelpers;

void BlockDisposeCallExisting(void *src)
{
    HelperFunction helper = (__bridge void *)[disposeHelpers objectForKey:(__bridge id)(src)];
    if (helper)
    {
        helper(src);
        [disposeHelpers removeObjectForKey:(__bridge id)(src)];
    }
    printf("BlockDisposeCallExisting %p\n", src);
}

void block_trap_dispose(void *aBlock)
{
    BlockObject *bObject = aBlock;
    if (bObject->flags & BLOCK_HAS_COPY_DISPOSE)
    {
        [disposeHelpers setObject:(__bridge id)(void *)bObject->descriptor->dispose_helper forKey:(__bridge id)(aBlock)];
        bObject->descriptor->dispose_helper = BlockDisposeCallExisting;
    }
    else
    {
        bObject->flags |= BLOCK_HAS_COPY_DISPOSE;
        bObject->descriptor->copy_helper = DummyBlockCopy;
        bObject->descriptor->dispose_helper = BlockDispose;
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    disposeHelpers = [NSMapTable.alloc initWithKeyOptions:(NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory | NSPointerFunctionsOpaquePersonality)
                                             valueOptions:(NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory | NSPointerFunctionsOpaquePersonality)
                                                 capacity:2];

    void (^b1)(void) = ^{ printf("hello world\n"); };
    printf("b1: %p\n", b1);
    b1();
    block_trap_dispose((__bridge void *)(b1));

    int x = 10;
    void (^b2)(void) = ^{ printf("x is %d\n", x); };
    printf("b2: %p\n", b2);
    b2();
    block_trap_dispose((__bridge void *)(b2));
    
    NSObject *anObject = NSObject.new;
    void (^b3)(void) = ^{ printf("anObject: %p\n", anObject); };
    printf("b3: %p\n", b3);
    b3();
    block_trap_dispose((__bridge void *)(b3));
}
```

Comment: sorry but I need to use C not Obj-C. Maybe the Obj-C compiler adds in some hidden C code on scope-exit and that's why it works for you?

Comment: Blocks are C, the dispose_helper is called when a block is disposed. So unless your blocks are not being disposed of by the Cocoa code you are calling but some other way it should be called. How are you allocating your blocks? How are they being decallocated? In Xcode if you do Project -> Perform Action -> Dissasemble you'll see exactly what the compiler is generating (block descriptors which match the ABI)

Comment: I create a __block_literal_1 and a __block_descriptor_1 per the ABI doc; set isa to _NSConcreteStackBlock, set flags = 1<<25 + 1<<26 + 1<<29, set invoke, dispose_helper and copy_helper to some callbacks that never get called. I'm not sure but I think in your example, blocks are disposed of on scope exit, which is a ObjC thing, not a C thing (which doesn't have RAII).

Comment: What I'm interested in is to see the refcount go up when a block is used by a method, say, [str enumerateLinesUsingBlock:myblock], and go down when that method ends, just like when an objects that wants to keep a reference to another objects calls retain() and then release() when it no longer needs that reference. I can't seem to create blocks that react to retain()/release() -- either taht, or enumerateLinesUsingBlock doesn't call retain()/release() on the block.

Comment: Yes, my test code is releasing the blocks but not with any special code - the compiler just inserts the equivalent of a release call. Your question says you're just trying to catch the disposal not trigger it so that difference is not relevant surely? Stacks blocks are not heap allocated... You may not be able to trust the refcount field, refcounts are not always stored with the object. Finally there is also probably no need for `enumerateLinesUsingBlock` to retain the block. However as it is a synchronous method you know when the block will be called no more - after the call returns. HTH

Comment: Well, I need to do something when the block reaches refcount 0 and is deallocated, but I'm not sure that blocks are refcounted even, at least not when created manually, from C. I don't want to track the the lifetime of blocks myself, just as I don't have to do that with objects. That's the end goal.

Comment: If you copy your block onto the heap (using `Block_copy()`) then when it is disposed the disposed helper will be called. However it doesn't look like that will solve your problem as `enumerateLinesUsingBlock` may not take ownership and even if it did as its a *synchronous* call there is no easy way for you to relinquish your ownership before it returns. You know when the block is no longer needed - when `enumerateLinesUsingBlock` returns. So if you've put it on the heap release then (`Block_release()`) and the dispose helper will be called, or just call your cleanup code directly.